# Escape line breaks in puts output

Tags: ruby, irb, ruby-1.8.7

In IRB on Ruby 1.8.7, I have a collection of strings I'm working with that have newlines in them. When these newlines are output, I want to explicitly see the `\r` and `\n` characters within my strings. Is there some way to tell `puts` to escape those characters, or a method similar to `puts` that will do what I want?

Note that directly evaluating each string isn't satisfactory because I want to be able to do something like this:

```
=> mystrings.each { |str| puts str.magical_method_to_escape_special_chars }
This is\na string in mystrings.
This is another\n\rstring.
```

And don't want to have to do this:

```
=> mystrings[0]
"This is\na string in mystrings."
=> mystrings[1]
"This is another\n\rstring."
...
=> mystrings[1000]
"There are a lot of\n\nstrings!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.8.7 :001 > s = "hi\nthere"
 => "hi\nthere" 
1.8.7 :002 > p s
"hi\nthere"
```

Answer (score 6):

I can use the `string#dump` method:

```
=> mystrings.each { |str| puts str.dump }
This is\na string in mystrings.
This is another\n\rstring.
```

According to the [Ruby documention for String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-dump), `string#dump`

> Produces a version of str with all nonprinting characters replaced by
>   \nnn notation and all special characters escaped.